# Accessing Web3 in trufflebox's react-auth-box

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript, react, truffle-box

Hi I am using trufflebox boilerplate [react-auth-box](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-auth-box). Created a new component called `Foo` where I am trying to access the `web3` object that has been mapped from Store to `this.props`.

However the `console.log(this.props.web3)` is showing `{web3Instance: null}`. What should we do?

**src/Foo.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Foo extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.props.web3)               // {web3Instance: null}
    }

    render() {
        return ( <div>foo</div> )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        web3: state.web3
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Factory);
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import { UserIsAuthenticated, UserIsNotAuthenticated } from './util/wrappers.js'
import getWeb3 from './util/web3/getWeb3'

// Layouts
import App from './App'
import Home from './layouts/home/Home'
import Dashboard from './layouts/dashboard/Dashboard'
import SignUp from './user/layouts/signup/SignUp'
import Profile from './user/layouts/profile/Profile'
import Foo from './Foo'

// Redux Store
import store from './store'

// Initialize react-router-redux.
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

// Initialize web3 and set in Redux.
getWeb3
.then(results => {
  console.log('Web3 initialized!')
})
.catch(() => {
  console.log('Error in web3 initialization.')
})

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="dashboard" component={UserIsAuthenticated(Dashboard)} />
          <Route path="signup" component={UserIsNotAuthenticated(SignUp)} />
          <Route path="profile" component={UserIsAuthenticated(Profile)} />
          <Route path="foo" component={Foo} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  ),
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ReactDOM.render` is happening before the `getWeb3` is done.

use your `store` to `dispatch` an action such as

```
{
  type:  WEB3_LOADED,
  payload: results
}
```

and add a reducer called `web3` that injects the action's `payload` into the `state` as `web3`

```
const reducer = (state = { web3: null }, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
      case WEB3_LOADED: return { web3: action.payload }
      default: return state
   }
}
```